# does wso2 esb xml transform support grovvy

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I know that I can use xslt to transform xml, but it costs a lot. 
I would like to know whether it is possible using grovvy or not. 
Assume I have two xml schema, and transfer them into java file, build to class and deploy to esb. 
And I transfer xml via groovy so that I can dynamically change the mapping without deployment java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [Groovy sample I wrote using WSO2 ESB Script mediator](https://udaraliyanage.wordpress.com/2016/08/13/executing-groovy-in-wso2-script-mediator/). This is for Json payload. However you can do the same for XML. Get payload using mc.getPayloadXML() method and use Groovy XmlSlurper class to parse xml to Groovy objects.

Comment: This is a sample for xml payload https://udaraliyanage.wordpress.com/2016/08/14/executing-groovy-in-wso2-script-mediator-part-2-xml/

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 ESB supports Mediators implemented in a variety of scripting languages such as JavaScript, Groovy. (https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Script+Mediator)

To execute a Groovy script using the WSO2 ESB's script mediator follow below tutorial

http://heshans.blogspot.com/2011/05/executing-groovy-scripts-using-wso2-esb.html

Comment: looks cool, is it just supported in esb4.8.1? when I am reviewing the sample of 4.8, I didn't find the sample of groovy.